# Java: Acceder a método de una subclase de un array

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente estructura de clases:

[image: diagrama]

En la clase Tablero tengo un array de tipo Pieza:

```
Tablero:    
Pieza aCoord[][] = new Pieza[8][8];
```

Y tengo instanciados los arrays con un New de tipo Peon, que es heredero de Pieza:

```
Tablero:    
public void prepararTablero(){
        for(int y = 0; y<8 ; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x<8 ; x++){
                if(y == 1){
                    //Peones blancos
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Peon("p"+x,y,x,true);
                }else if(y == 6){
                    //Peones Negros
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Peon("P"+x,y,x,false);
                }else{
                    //Huecos restantes
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Vacio(y+"."+x);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Según este código, en la posición del array aCoord[ 1 ][ 1 ] hay instanciado un objeto de tipo Peón.

El problema me viene cuando intento acceder al método movimientoPieza(Pieza[ ] [ ] array, boolean direccion), este es un método abstracto en Pieza que se define en Peón. La función no hace nada de momento,

```
Pieza:
public abstract void movimientoPieza(Pieza[][] array, boolean direccion);

Peon:
public void movimientoPieza(Pieza[][] array, boolean direccion){
//Vacio
}

Main:
t1.aCoord[1][1].movimientoPieza(t1.aCoord , true);
```

Quiero acceder al método movimientoPieza desdel array, pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class Peon does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void movimientoPieza(Pieza[][], boolean)' of abstract class Pieza.
        at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Dejo aquí el código de todas las clases:

```
Main:
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Objetos
        Tablero t1 = new Tablero();

        t1.prepararTablero();
        t1.mostrarTablero();
        System.out.print(t1.aCoord[1][1].getNombre() + "\n");
        t1.aCoord[1][1].movimientoPieza(t1.aCoord , true);
    }
}

Tablero:

public class Tablero{
    Pieza aCoord[][] = new Pieza[8][8];

    public void prepararTablero(){
        for(int y = 0; y<8 ; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x<8 ; x++){
                if(y == 1){
                    //Peones blancos
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Peon("p"+x,y,x,true);
                }else if(y == 6){
                    //Peones Negros
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Peon("P"+x,y,x,false);
                }else{
                    //Huecos restantes
                    aCoord[y][x] = new Vacio(y+"."+x);
                }

            }
        }

        //resto de piezas
        //blancos
        aCoord[0][0] = new Torre("t"+0,0,0,true);
        aCoord[0][7] = new Torre("t"+7,0,7,true);
        //Negros
        aCoord[7][0] = new Torre("T"+7,7,0,false);
        aCoord[7][7] = new Torre("T"+7,7,7,false);
    }

    public void mostrarTablero(){
        for(int y = 0; y<8 ; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x<8 ; x++){
                System.out.print(aCoord[y][x].getNombre()+" |");
                if(x == 7){
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Pieza:

public abstract class Pieza{
    //Atributos
    private String nombre;
    private int posY;
    private int posX;
    private boolean color; //true: Blancas false: Negras

    //Setters
    public void setNombre(String _nom){
        this.nombre = _nom;
    }
    public void setPosY(int _posY){
        this.posY = _posY;
    }
    public void setPosX(int _posX){
        this.posX = _posX;
    }
    public void setColor(boolean _color){
        this.color = _color;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
    public int getPosY(){
        return this.posY;
    }
    public int getPosX(){
        return this.posX;
    }
    public boolean getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }

    //Métodos
    public abstract void movimientoPieza(Pieza[][] array, boolean direccion);
}


Peon:

public class Peon extends Pieza{
    //Atributos


    //Constructores
    public Peon(String _nom, int _posY, int _posX,boolean _color){
        super.setNombre(_nom);
        super.setPosY(_posY);
        super.setPosX(_posX);
        super.setColor(_color);
    }

    //Métodos
    public void movimientoPieza(Pieza[][] array, boolean direccion){
        //Variables
        //int posXInic = super.getPosX();
        //int posYInic = super.getPosY();
        //int color = super.getColor();

        //Direccion: false-Izq, true-Der
        //Color: true-Blanc , false-Negr

        if(direccion && color){

        }else{

        }

        //Vaciamos la posicion Inicial
        //array[posYInic][posXInic] = new Vacio(posYInic+"."+posXInic);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "PosX: " + super.getPosX() + " PosY: " + super.getPosY();
    }
}
```

Comment: No sé mucho sobre el tema pero por si sirve de ayuda se me ocurre que puedes utilizar la anotación "@Override" previa implementación del método en la clase Peon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un error poco común cuando usas un IDE, porque éste se suele encargar de compilar todo antes de ejecutar el código. La forma de reproducir este error que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

1. Creas una clase abstracta `Pieza`.
2. Creas una clase que hereda de `Pieza` (`Peon`).
3. Compilas todo y ejecutas (funciona)
4. Añades a la clase `Pieza` un método abstracto.
5. Añades el método faltante a `Peon`.
6. Compilas la clase `Pieza`, pero no la clase `Peon`.
7. Ejecutas el código usando la nueva clase compilada (Pieza.class) junto con la antigua (Peon.class), que no tiene el método creado.

Mi consejo es que te asegures de que todo el código está compilado a la vez, quizá borrando todos los ficheros .class de tu proyecto.

Comment: En vez de hacer todo eso, me he descargado el eclipse. Muchísimas gracias, nunca me hubiera imaginado que el error iba a ser el entorno.